# ISNUMBER returning FALSE for cell that has only numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In cell A1, for example, I have the product code `BW224`

In B1, I have `=RIGHT(A1,3)` as I only want the numbers. Result of formula is 224

In C1, I have `ISNUMBER(B1)`, which returns FALSE

Why is this and how can I get around it?

This is an overly simplified example, but If I can get a way round the above I can adapt it. My actual sheet needs to (In pseudocode):

> Take the 3 right-most numerical characters of a target cell and output them to the current cell, if the target cell contains junk like "zzzzzz" or anything other than a proper product code (like in A1), the output of the formula needs to be blank or 0

Comment: What's the definition of "proper product code"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `=ISNUMBER(VALUE(B1))` on `C1`

Also check `=ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1))` which will be `FALSE`

Answer (score 7):

Because the cell might be showing `224` but the cell content is `=RIGHT(A1, 3)` which is not a number.

You can use `VALUE` with your `ISNUMBER` to check what the cell shows instead of its contents

```
=ISNUMBER(VALUE(B1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Demo.

The RIGHT formula returns a string. If there's a value, use the formula VALUE to turn this string into a value. In this case:

1. First option. In cell B1, use `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,3))`
2. Second option. In cell C1, use `=ISNUMBER(VALUE(B1))`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other offers do not answer the question:

```
=IFERROR(1*RIGHT(A1,3),0)
```